# Error while running VS tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I've bumped into a very strange problem lately with my friend while using unit test framework in Visual Studio 2010. We have created TestProject (let's call it NoTitleTests) that references few libraries ("casual" and "xna" dlls) and it works without any problem.
But when we added NoTitle project (which is a XNA game) to references, when we launch our units tests, VS comes up with error window:

```
"This interface is not supported. 
(Exception from HRESULT:0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))"
```

(may differ a bit on english Windows, I've translated).

Funny thing is, that we got this error even if our unit test project contains zero tests. It compiles fine (as no code is in project, it would be hard to not compile :-) ).

Answer (score 2):

Hey, a bit late, but maybe it helps others :-? ran into the same problem a couple of minutes ago.

Remove all references from your test project that reference projects containing game content.

see > http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/63814/63814.aspx

cu, mm72

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it didn't help in our project though, cause tests work only if we remove reference to content project from all projects in solution, including game project itself, which is not something we want to do. The only way to test logic is to move it to different dll project. I guess it can be considered a bug. Thanks for link that explains it, +1.